# Find the nearest coordinate (wgs84)

Tags: sql, database, wgs84

I've gotten a database filled with addresses and WGS84 coordinates to where I compute, within a range of 0 to 50 km, how many addresses is in the parameter.

SQL:

```
DECLARE @Lat float, @Long float;
DECLARE @MaxRange int, @MinRange int, @RangeDivisor float, @RangeEnhed varchar(10);
SET @MinRange = 0; -- Minimumsafstand fra punkt
SET @MaxRange = 50; -- Maksimumaftand fra punkt
SET @RangeDivisor = 1000; -- Enhedslængde
SET @RangeEnhed = 'KM'; -- Enhed

USE Potentiale
SELECT @Lat = dbo.HeleDanmark_DAWA.wgs84koordinat_bredde, @Long = dbo.HeleDanmark_DAWA.wgs84koordinat_længde
FROM dbo.HeleDanmark_DAWA WHERE KVHx = '10100040014010000'; -- Skiftes ud så vi har noget at søge på (Std.: Abel Catrhines Gade 14 = 10100040014010000)

WITH Distance AS (
SELECT
  KVHx,
  wgs84koordinat_bredde,
  wgs84koordinat_længde,
  Geog.STDistance(geography::Point(@Lat, @Long, 4326))/@RangeDivisor [Afstand],
  @RangeEnhed [Enhed]
FROM dbo.HeleDanmark_DAWA)

SELECT KVHx, wgs84koordinat_længde AS Long, wgs84koordinat_bredde AS Lat, Afstand, Enhed
FROM Distance
WHERE Afstand <= @MaxRange AND Afstand >= @MinRange 
ORDER BY Afstand
```

I then have this sample:
Table1 (Main table)

```
Latitude          |     Longitude
-------------------------------------
55.5313963845829  | 8.35251516977335
55.5312443688612  | 8.35277495818283
55.5301254735429  | 8.35153843756768
55.5611352006539  | 8.47886488626897
55.5604841267899  | 8.47779554332068
55.5624113202676  | 8.47854023997904
55.560663076283   | 8.47289325417751
```

Table2 (then one I want to match the closets to table1 data!)

```
Latitude    | Longitude
-------------------------
55,497922   | 8,45101581
55,60777589 | 8,504865646
55,12208021 | 9,066325298
55,81149643 | 8,642359956
55,55564138 | 8,846147399
55,26855212 | 9,180423727
55,61868893 | 8,474493713
55,73017722 | 8,221978913
```

How do I find ex the nearest WGS84 to lat='55,497922' AND Long='8,45101581'. 
My sql skills seems limited as to this. I tried with "WHERE Table.wgs84long=LIKE xxx", but that didn't work out that well.

Articles would be much appreciated too :)

Comment: Is the problem that the results include entries other than the second entry (which should be the closest point to the given lat long that is not the given lat long)?

Comment: @JerryFederspiel: Yes! Sorry if I made my self unclear, english isn't my first language :)

The sample I provided was the the second table! 
I can provide a small sample of my main table I wish to compare with!

Comment: @JerryFederspiel: I've provided the main table now :)

Comment: Do you want to match each point in Table1 to its closest point in Table2?

Comment: Other way around. I want to match the points in table 2 with table 1!